# Mock window.close() in React-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

I have searched online but I didn't find a way to mock `window.close()` in react testing library or even in jest.

```
const handleClose = () => {
window.opener.location.reload()
window.close()
}

<Button
  data-test-id="close"
  onClick={handleClose}
/>
```

How do I achieve test case coverage for the `onclick` of button and `window.close()`  and `window.opener.location.reload()` is covered

My test case is as follows:

```
const wrapper = render( <CloseButton />);
const windowSpy = jest.spyOn(global, 'window', 'get');

const { queryByTestId } = wrapper;
fireEvent.click(queryByTestId('close');
expect(windowSpy.opener.location.relaod).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
expect(windowSpy.close).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

for this last line of code

```
expect(windowSpy.close).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

I am getting an error that says

> received value must be a mock or spy function. received has value
> undefined

For

```
expect(windowSpy.opener.location.relaod).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

it says:

> `windowSpy.opener` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

You're only mocking window but you're not providing any implementation.

This should help:

```
windowSpy.mockImplementation(() => ({
  close: jest.fn(),
  opener: {
      location: {
          reload: jest.fn(),
      }
  }
}));
```

Comment: @Axnyff- How do i also mock window.opener.location.reload because in this case it says window.opener is not defined

Comment: Can you add that object next to the close property ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't actually need a spy, just a mock, I've had luck with simply reassigning the particular window function:

```
global.window.opener.location.reload = jest.fn()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Remarkable Mark](https://remarkablemark.org/) provides a solution to this that avoids all the above pitfalls, as well as the `reload is not declared configurable` error that you may get when you try to modify `reload()` directly. See:

https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2018/11/17/mock-window-location/

Code is copied here directly from this ^ page:

```js
describe('window.location', () => {
  const { location } = window;

  beforeAll(() => {
    delete window.location;
    window.location = { reload: jest.fn() };
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    window.location = location;
  });

  it('mocks `reload`', () => {
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(window.location.reload)).toBe(true);
  });

  it('calls `reload`', () => {
    window.location.reload();
    expect(window.location.reload).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Thanks Mark!

https://remarkablemark.org/support/